# How to replace column values (ID) in a data frame to (VALUE) by looking up another data frame that has ID and VALUE

Tags: r

I have a data frame that about 200 rows and 3 columns. Second column is called Age but it has codes that I need to look up a different Age Group data frame that has Code and Value.

df1 (for people) is below:

```
Name Age Address
==== === ======
John  0   something
Mel   1   something
Sandy 0   something
Shawn 2   something
(and so on for about 200 rows)

df2 (for age group)
Code   Value
====   =====
0       Minor
1       Adult    
2       Senior
```

I am unable to figure out the command to change my df1 to be like below. I need to keep the same column names as before although it is changing from numeric to string. Please help! I'm stuck.

```
Name Age        Address
==== ===       ======
John  Minor   something
Mel   Adult   something
Sandy Minor   something
Shawn Senior   something
```

Thank you in advance!

I tried

```
df1$Age = df2[match(df1$Age,df2$Code),"Value"]
```

and it seemed to work in that in R Studio the df1 data frame seemed to have proper replacements, but when I tried to write df1 to csv, it had a messed up file. The text in the file had "c(Minor, ....)." When I did head(df1, 10) just to see if this replaced df1 was printing, it showed no values.

Answer (score 1):

We could use a `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, join_by(Age == Code)) %>% 
  select(Name, Age = Value, Address)
```

```
   Name    Age   Address
1  John  Minor something
2   Mel  Adult something
3 Sandy  Minor something
4 Shawn Senior something
```